# Creating pdfs with Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am trying to create a separate pdf of each sheet in an Excel Workbook. This is the code I am using.

```
Sub CreatePdfs()
' CreatePdfs Macro
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+o
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsA As Worksheet
Dim wbA As Workbook 
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String
Dim myFile As Variant
For Each ws In Worksheets
Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsA = ActiveSheet
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"
strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")
strFile = strName & ".pdf"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile
ws.Select
nm = wsA.Name

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPathFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next ws 
End Sub
```

This "almost" works. It creates a separate pdf file for each sheet (as it is supposed to) and saves it in the same folder as the Excel file (like it's supposed to) but names it incorrectly. For instance if there are 4 sheets in the workbook named 1, 2, 3, and 4, then it creates sheet 2 as a pdf and names it "1." It names 3 as "2", 4 as "3" and 1 as "4".

I must have something out of order in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you avoid using `.Select` then you will not face that problem. You do not need the lines `Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook` and `Set wsA = ActiveSheet`.  Also `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF...` becomes `ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF...`

Try this code

```
Sub CreatePdfs()
    ' CreatePdfs Macro
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+o
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strPath As String, strFile As String, strPathFile As String

    strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    If strPath = "" Then strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        strName = Replace(Replace(ws.Name, " ", ""), ".", "_")
        strFile = strName & ".pdf"
        strPathFile = strPath & strFile

        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strPathFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Cleaned up my macro from this. Tweeked it a little because it didn't save it to the same folder. It was in the folder a tier above part of the path at the beginning of each filename. It's rocking now. Making 4 pdfs in about 2 minutes!

Comment: So I hope your problem is sorted? :)